# Separating the _____ from the _____

Tags: code-golf

There are two types of people in this world: users and admins. Let's find out who the real admins are.

The task is simple:
If the script is run with elevation, print 'True' and only 'True' (only trailing newlines permitted as extra). If the script is run as an unelevated user, print 'False' and only 'False', exceptions granted for trailing new lines.

The code can be run on any operating system which is currently available free of charge, or on any CPU architecture as a code insertion OR it can run on Windows 10.

The selected operating system must have at least 3 privilege levels, and should return 'True' for any execution of code above the default user privilege level.

I couldn't find any tags for this, so please if you have suggestions, name them. Good luck!

Comment: On *nix systems, would it be valid to test that either a) the user has UID 0? or b) the user belongs to group 0? (TBH, I don't think that any of these methods correctly address the _above the default user privilege level_ question. But I ask just to be sure.)

Comment: Is this [tag:decision-problem] (even though there's no input)? Would you consider relaxing the output requirements so that any two consistent truthy/falsy values are allowed?

Comment: What's "elevation"?

Comment: Why the requirement for 3 privilege levels? That's pretty bizarre. Common operating systems only have two and the challenge requires a boolean result. All the existing answers check admin/non-admin without caring about some third level.

Comment: I feel like this question lacks a good definition of "privilege level". Two of the three current answers make specific assumptions about system configuration. And with things like capabilities and namespacing (under linux) the distinction what counts as "elevated" doesn't always seem easy.

Comment: @ManfP Privilege levels are built directly into x86 hardware. This isn't hat hard.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Name one operating system with two privelege levels.

Comment: @tuskiomi Unix without containers, capabilities or security frameworks. You're either root or you aren't. None of the existing answers account for anything beyond admin/non-admin, and would be wrong under any interpretation where the OS has more than 2 privilege levels.

Comment: @tuskiomi You are conflating x86's notion of "privileged" with the OS's. On all common consumer OSs, all user-mode code (including that of root/admin/...) will run as "unprivileged" user-mode, as far as x86 is concerned. It's only through syscalls to the kernel that a root-user process is able to access more resources.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' something that's downloadable and installable, something that's not 50 years old, and valid for this challenge?

Comment: @ManfP and interrupts, and protected memory ranges, and certain context changes. a lot more than syscalls.

Comment: @tuskiomi A program running as root user *can't* perform arbitrary (physical) memory access, nor can it directly access hardware. It can only ask the kernel to do so via syscalls. "priviledged" has a very different meaning when talking about processes than when talking about CPUs.

Comment: @ManfP Ah! So then there is a 3rd privilege level for the kernel!

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 32 bytes

-13 bytes thanks to @Arnauld
-1 byte thanks to @Dingus

```python
import os
print(os.getuid()<1e3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRCG/mKugKDOvRCO/WC89taQ0M0VD08bQwMBA8/9/AA)

Comment: I'm not really sure how this works, but the code should be equivalent to `print(1000!=os.getuid())`.

Comment: @ovs I was about to ask the same thing. I think it's more like `print(os.getuid()<1000)`, but I don't really speak Python.

Comment: @Arnauld oof, just realized that. Stupid mistake on my part.

Comment: You could save one byte on MacOS, where user ids start at 501 instead of 1000.

Comment: You could also save a byte by changing `1000` to `1e3`.

Comment: @Dingus cool, edited!

Comment: Assuming this is meant for a unix-like platform, this is overly long and incorrect. 1000 is not a meaningful cutoff for privileges. User id 0 is privileged and others are not.

Comment: I don't think this is even right in practice on most linux systems - 1000 is where *normal users* start, daemons (which mostly run just as unpriviledged) will be below that.

Comment: @ManfP Exactly; it will output True whenever it is not being run as a normal user.

Comment: @sugarfl But "normal user" isn't the same as "unelevated user", it's more like "account intended for an actual human". A daemon can (and often will) run with even lower privileges than most users, and is not inherently privileged in any way. Only root (euid=0 in the root user namespace) is getting special ("privileged") treatment from the kernel, and that too keeps getting replaced by CAP_SYS_ADMIN etc.

Comment: @sugarfi There is no difference between the privileges granted to users ids in the system range and users ids in the user range. It's just a cutoff for the user creation program to use different defaults.

Answer (score 9):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>39</s> <s>31</s> 27 bytes

Saved 4 bytes thanks to [Gilles 'SO- stop being evil'](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/994/gilles-so-stop-being-evil)!!!

```bash
a=False
>/a&&a=True
echo $a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P9HWLTGnOJXLTj9RTS3RNqSoNJUrNTkjX0El8f9/AA)

Works on any *nix system.

**Explanation**

```bash
a=False         # set env variable a to False
>/a             # try to create (>) (or overwrite if it exists) file /a 
                # but directory / has root write privileges 
                # and if /a is created by root in a
                # previous run the file will have root only 
                # write privileges
   &&a=True     # if this succeeds set a to True
                # if this fails a will be left as is   
echo $a         # will be True for root and False otherwise
```

Comment: Creating new files in `/bin` should also be disallowed for non-root, so you could use `>/bin/9` or something that isn't an existing file on standard systems.  Or `>/9` should work; any sane system won't have unprivileged users able to create files in the root directory.  On my Arch GNU/Linux system, `/`, `/bin` and `/bin/[` have the same rwx-xr-x permissions, and no ACLs, so this fails for all non-root users.  The question talks about systems with 3 permission levels; IDK if accounts like `systemd-journal` have *more* persmissions; just different.

Comment: I feel that trashing your system is an undesirable side-effect...

Comment: @PeterCordes Indeed the privileges of `/bin` itself only allow root to create files there, changed.

Comment: @Neil It shows the great responsibility the comes with the power of root! T_T

Comment: You can remove `/bin`.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Came back to make that change - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 32 bytes

```
fltmc>nul&&echo True||echo False
```

Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28268802/182705) Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: you can cut two bytes if you redirect to a single-letter file

Comment: @peterferrie Surely that will throw an error if you don't have the rights to create the file? For a question where rights are important, I wouldn't want to mess it up!